# SQL Server stored procedure working fine on SSMS, timed out with .net Application

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Below is the program which is calling a stored procedure. It is throwing an error:

> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated

But the same procedure returns a response in less than a second in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getlargestmarketshare("842", "107", "1", "2", "", "", "10", "2014", "2015", "2", "HS");
        }

        public static String getlargestmarketshare(String ReporterCode, String PartnerCode, String TradeFlowCode, String AG, String CommodityCode, String SectorRange, String SectorLimit, String FromYear, String ToYear, String AggregationLevel, string Classification)
        {
            string json = "";

            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    string query = "sp_GetLargestMarketShare";

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        if (ReporterCode != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReporterCode", ReporterCode);
                        }

                        if (PartnerCode != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartnerCode", PartnerCode);
                        }

                        if (TradeFlowCode != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TradeFlowCode", TradeFlowCode);
                        }

                        if (AG != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AG", AG);
                        }

                        if (CommodityCode != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommodityCode", CommodityCode);
                        }

                        if (SectorRange != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectorRange", SectorRange);
                        }

                        if (AggregationLevel != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AggregationLevel", AggregationLevel);
                        }  /**/

                        if (SectorLimit != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Limit", SectorLimit);
                        }

                        if (FromYear != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromYear", FromYear);
                        }

                        if (ToYear != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToYear", ToYear);
                        }

                        if (Classification != "")
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Classification", Classification);
                        }

                        SqlDataAdapter adpater = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        adpater.Fill(ds, "Records");
                        Console.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
                        Console.Read();
                    }
                }

                var data = new
                {
                    Records = ds.Tables[0],
                    DBResponse = ds.Tables[1],
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                json = ex.Message;
            }
            return json;
        }
}
```

Connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Server=XXXXXXXX; Database=XXXX; User Id=HDDev; password=XXXXX;Connect Timeout=2000" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Can you try increasing command time out (Not connection time-out) to check whether execution time is the issue . By default this value is 30 secs. syntax should be cmd.CommandTimeout = 300. Also are you sure you get the result in Management studio in 1 sec when you run the procedure for the first time in a new query window? PS: Increasing connection timeout doesn't have any effect here.

Comment: Going by the parameters you send, this is a classic "optional predicate" parameter sniffing issue. The short answer is to add `WITH RECOMPILE` to your stored procedure. But there's a lot more to it than that.

Comment: @Wijitha Connection Timeout specified is 2000. At SSMS its giving result in less than a second.

Comment: Yeah I can see that connection timeout is 2000 in connection string. But I was talking about command time which are two different things. Set the command timeout in code and try again. Add this following to above  adpater.Fill(ds, "Records"); in your code. cmd.CommandTimeout = 300.

Comment: Don't extend the timeout to fix a parameter sniffing issue. Fix the parameter sniffing issue.